# OpenLayers popup not toggling

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers

When I create a static marker and attach a static popup, things seem to work fine. I am trying to build dynamic markers, and while the marker's and popup's are being created correctly, they are no longer toggling due to events.

I've stripped the code down to just enough to bring the map up and draw one constructed marker/popup duo. Maybe you can see something I'm missing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">html,body,#basicMap{width:69%;height:60%;}</style>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>

        /**/var oldProjection=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");//Used to scale the GPS coordinates
        /**/var newProjection=new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");//To the map
        /**/var marks=new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Debug Site");
        /**/var mapnik=new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("World Map");//Layer containing the map tiles
        /**/var size=new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);//Icon height and width
        /**/var offset=new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2),-size.h);//Icon offset
        /**/var mapCenter=new OpenLayers.LonLat(-125.2,54.8).transform(oldProjection,newProjection);

        function init() 
        {        
            var map=new OpenLayers.Map($("BasicMap"),{controls:[]});
            map.addLayer(mapnik);
            map.setCenter(mapCenter,3);
            map.addLayer(marks);
            var TestSite=new site(-131,57.2,"TestSite","DE","Hello World");
            map.addPopup(TestSite.popup);
        }
        function site(lon,lat,siteID,layer,content)
        {
            this.content=content;
            this.layer=layer;
            this.lon=lon;this.lat=lat;this.siteID=siteID;
            this.lonlat=new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat).transform(oldProjection,newProjection);
            this.popup=new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored(this.siteID,this.lonlat,new OpenLayers.Size(150,375),this.content);
            this.marker=new OpenLayers.Marker(this.lonlat);
            this.popup.border='1px solid black';this.popup.autoSize=true;
            this.marker.events.register("click",this.marker,function(e){this.popup.toggle()});
            marks.addMarker(this.marker);   
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();"><div id="basicMap"></div></body>
```